# What is the difference between Unity and Unity.WebApi packages

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2, unity-container

I am currently using Unity nuget package in my web api project, but from the description of that package it's a light weight Ioc container. My question is what is the difference between Unity and Unity.WebApi nuget packages? I want to make sure that I am not missing something needed in unity.webapi that unity does not have.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried opening the packages yourself to take a look? `.nupkg` files are just zip archives.

Comment: MVC and WebAPI use different dependency resolvers.  Check out the documentation on Unity.WebAPI - https://github.com/devtrends/Unity.WebAPI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply, the Unity.WebApi package makes it simple to integrate Unity in a WebApi project by wiring up the basic components for you.

It does this by adding a pre-defined unity configuration class which you just reference in your Application_Start event.

If you have Unity already configured and working, you don't need it and it's not a requirement for using Unity with WebApi.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense.